# Passing parameters to buttons

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm dealing with a problem where I need to be able to pass particular arguments to a button's `onClick` method. What I want to do is something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int clicked = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageButton btn = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new WhenClicked(btn, getApplicationContext()));
    }

    public static void incrementClicked()
    {
        clicked += 1;
    }
}
```

I know one way to make this work is by having our own "OnClickListener", but then I run into a problem of dealing with `context` since I want to spawn a new intent.

A solution like this could kind of work, but has some big problems

```
public class WhenClicked implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context context; //this is obviously bad
    private ImageButton imgbtn;


    public WhenClicked(ImageButton imgbutton, Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.imgbtn = imgbutton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        imgbtn.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 255, 255, 255));
        MainActivity.incrementClicked();
        //now to spawn an activity
    }
}
```

Edit: Since the question seems unclear, I've edited in my working solution. The problem now becomes finding a way that we don't need to store the context as an instance variable.

Comment: Please declare `btn` as a field rather than a local variable in the scope of `onCreate()`. And about the **context** problem, you can also have another field variable of it and assign it the value `MainActivity.this` inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: does btn HAVE to be private? can it have the default or protected access specifier instead?

Comment: @VardaanSharma I don't really think so. What would the implications be if it were to be public?

Comment: which argument do you want to pass to onClick? please provide some detail regarding your intention

Comment: public would basically mean classes outside of the scope of your class can modify it. This could lead to accidental modification of this variable or is some extreme cases any third party malicious code could try and manipulate your variable (not sure what the impact would be though)

default/protected would limit the scope such that only inner classes can affect your code. Default would be preferable as with protected, even classes that extend your class can modify it.

As a general rule of thumb, one should always strive to minimize the access scope

Comment: another alternative, is to store it in your shared prefs.

Comment: clicked  is Activity level... u can easily change it in onclick as clicked++.. what is the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your button on Activity level and make it private, it will be visible inside inner class - **OnClickListener**. About context, you can access it inside **onClick** like this `MainActivity.this`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int clicked = 0;

    private ImageButton btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2); 
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                btn.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 255, 255, 255));//sets a tint

                // PART YOU ARE INTERESTED IN
                clicked++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Someclass.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you need this as your custom Listener Class you can do this:

```
public class CustomOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    int clicked = 0 ;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // here comes View, not ImageButton, so you should check if it is ImageButton and then set tint
        if (v instanceof ImageButton) {
            ((ImageButton)v).setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 255, 255, 255));
        }

        // PART YOU ARE INTERESTED IN
        clicked++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Someclass.class);
    }
}
```

As you see here you have context - `v.getContext()` . Eveny *View* holds context, so it is accessible from clickListener and you don't need to pass it through constructor.

Comment: That does seem to be a more efficient solution than my edit. Is there a way to put that into our own custom OnClickListener class?

Comment: Sure, you can do it in custom OnClickListener . See my updated answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no need to make anything static or pass context to another class. A simple way to do this would be to **make your Activity implement OnClickListener**. Set the current instance of Activity as click listener and get a callback in the onClick() method which has View as a parameter. You can easily get the image button's click here by checking the view id. This is also the best method to use when you have to deal with clicks of multiple views in your layout.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int clicked = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageButton btn = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        //set click listener
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                 //Imagebutton is clicked
                 i++;
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```